# Creating Hotspots for Resizable Image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink, imagemap

Since I was not able to create a horizontal navigation bar with the desired text, I had to create a new `navbar` in illustrator and save it as a jpeg. I am planning on using hotspots over the words `home` and `products`. Of course, now the problem is that as a user resizes their browser, they still need to click on the links. What is the best way to go about doing this? Do I really need to map out every single spot for where the words could be on the page as the user resizes their browser?

Here are three different places where the words `home` and `products` will appear on the page as the user resizes. `Home` and `Products` move left and right between the first and second screenshots, and up and down between the second and third screenshots. Besides that the words are pretty much fixed on the page.
[image: Resize 3]
[image: Resize 2] 
[image: Resize 1]

My fear is that the user could find a hotspot for a word that isn't there. How can I prevent this? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#banner {width:100%}
#banner img {width:100%;height:auto}
nav {width:100%;display:block;}
nav ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
background-color:#c0872e;}
nav li {display:inline-block;background-color:#c0872e;
font-family:Georgia;}
nav a {line-height:35px; color:white; padding: 0 30px; font-size:22px;
 font-family:Georgia; background-color:#c0872e;}
nav a:hover {text-decoration:none}

a{float:left;margin-right:58px; margin-left:58px;color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}
body {background-image: url("daikinbackground1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
}

-->
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>daikininc.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
<header>
<div>
<div style="text-align:center" id="banner">
<title="daikinincbanner">
<img src="daikinbanner1.jpg" border="0" alt="daikinbanner1">
</div>
<!--
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
-->
<nav style="text-align:center">
<img style ="height:300px" width="1355" src="navbarimage1.jpg">
</nav>
<br>
<p style="text-align:center;font-family:WindsorDemi;">
<font size="4">
Welcome to daikininc.com! Home to the world's greatest eggorll
wrappers and noodles.
</font>
</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</nav>
</header>
<section>
<aside>
</aside>
<article>
</article>
<footer>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Since I was not able to create a horizontal navigation bar with the desired text" ?  [This is a simplified example](http://output.jsbin.com/vusuqa/1/)... What are you trying to achieve that can't be done with CSS and no images?

Comment: I tried to use Windsor Bold as the font in the Navigation Bar. Even though I downloaded it to my computer, it wasn't showing up in the browser (it was still showing up as the default font), and I know that there are a limited number of fonts that will show up on everyone Else's browser unless they have that specific font downloaded.

Comment: The font inside the horizontal nav bar HAS to be Windsor Bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT be doing this with images.  Find a web font version of Windsor and use that instead with `@font-face`.

css-tricks has a [nice write up on using @font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set of overlaying divs (with links inside) that are the same dimension as your image. If your image doesn't resize based on viewport, then you should set fix width/height/position on these divs.

That being said, I suggest that you build your design layout/style without using a big image like that. It'll save you some headaches.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not know I couldn't put code in a reply : )

Comment: Full html and css now in original post. Please explain what you mean by creating a set of overlaying divs if possible. Thank you.